# Robolectric packageinfo missing data

Tags: java, android, junit, gradle, robolectric

My app uses `versionName` of it's `PackageInfo` to determine the current version.

I'm trying to test a piece of code (using `JUnit`) the relies on that data, but Robolectric set `versionName` to null.
I looked into the source code and saw that the `PackageInfo` is initialized according to my `AndroidManifest.xml`.

My app's manifest doesn't contains versionName, it is set via android gradle plugin (which works great after a regular build, and I would like to keep it that way)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        versionName VERSION_NAME
    }
...
}
```

Any ideas how I can make the changes to the manifest occur in a test build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` constant instead of gathering it from `PackageInfo`.

However because `Robolectric` tests are run only for debug configuration it is not possible to check in `Robolectric` tests release configuration cases. But maybe it is not your case

Comment: Where is `BuildInfo` available? Google didn't with that one too much.

Comment: This is autogenerated file. It is already in your project. Just start typing and Android Studio will suggest you to import it

Comment: BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME may be what you mean here.

Comment: @TravisCastillo Exactly :) Works great